# Checking that the geometry for a triangle is contained in a list of lines

Tags: python, python-2.7, computational-geometry

I have a list of lines `Lines=([('B', 'C'), ('D', 'A'), ('D', 'C'), ('A', 'B'), ('D', 'B')])` and `geometry = ('B', 'C', 'D')` is a list of points that set up the triangle `(B,C,D)`.

I want to check whether `geometry` can be set up from list of lines in `Lines`. How can I create a function to check that status? `True` or `False`.

Sample Functionality with input Lines:

```
>> Lines=([('B', 'C'), ('D', 'A'), ('D', 'C'), ('A', 'B'), ('D', 'B'),])
>> geometry1 = ('B', 'C', 'D')
>> check_geometry(Lines, geometry1)
   True
>> geometry2 = ('A', 'B', 'E')
>> check_geometry(Lines, geometry2)
   False
```

This is my code, but the result is wrong:

```
import itertools

def check_geometry(line, geometry):
    dataE = [set(x) for x in itertools.combinations(geometry, 2)]
    for data in dataE:
       if data not in line:
           return False
    return True 

Lines = [('B', 'C'), ('D', 'A'), ('D', 'C'), ('A', 'B'), ('D', 'B'),]
geometry1 = ('B', 'C', 'D')
print check_geometry(Lines, geometry1)
```

Output:

```
False
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you actually have a tuple, of a list, of tuples.

Comment: For a triangle with the points (B, C, D), you effectively get the lines (B, C), (C, D) and (D, B). So if I understand you correctly, you want to see whether those are all present in `Lines`?

Comment: Why are you using tuples instead of lists? Also, please provide a *working* example of your code, ie: define `A, B, C`.

Comment: And what does "check whether geometry can set up from list of lines in Lines" mean? What do you mean by "set up"?

Comment: Are A,B,C,... strings?

Comment: @Gabriel sorry i mean "whether the geometry can be set up from lines in my list"

Comment: @timgeb I think A,B,C can be string or whatever which define a point that set up a line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### For triangles:

You could use the built-in **[`all`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#all)** to do this, making sure to first sort the list contents since their order might differ than that generated from **[`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)**:

```
sLines = [tuple(sorted(l)) for l in Lines]
dataE = itertools.combinations('BCD', 2)
```

Now you can call `all` which will check that every value in `dataE` is present in `sLines`:

```
all(l1 in sLines for l1 in dataE)
```

Which will return `True`.

So, your `check_geometry` function could look something like:

```
def check_geometry(line, geometry):
    sLines = [tuple(sorted(l)) for l in line]
    dataE = itertools.combinations(geometry, 2)
    return all(l1 in sLines for l1 in dataE)
```

Calls made will now check if the `Lines` contain the `geometry`:

```
check_geometry(Lines, 'BCD')
# returns True

check_geometry(Lines, 'ABE')
# returns False
```

---

#### A bit more general:

To generalize this a bit, we can drop `itertools.combinations` and instead utilize `zip`. The following makes some appropriate changes to the function in order to acommodate `zip` but performs similar stuff:

```
def check_geometry(line, geometry):
    sLines = [sorted(l) for l in line]
    dataE = [sorted(x) for x in zip(geometry, geometry[1:] + geometry[:1])] 
    return all(l1 in sLines for l1 in dataE)
```

The key difference here is:

`dataE` is now a list of lists containing the result of `zip(geometry, geometry[1:] + geometry[:1])`. What `zip` does in this case is it takes a string like `"BCDA"` and the same string with the first element added to the end `geometry[1:] + geometry[:1]` (i.e `"CDAB"`) and creates entries signifying the sides of a shape:

```
>>> s = "BCDA"

>>> s[1:] + s[:1]
>>> 'CDAB'

>>> list(zip(s, s[1:] + s[:1]))
[('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'A'), ('A', 'B')]
```

Now we can check that a geometry with points `"BCDA"` can be constructed by the lines in `Lines`:

```
check_geometry(Lines, "BCD")
# True

check_geometry(Lines, "BCDA")
# True

check_geometry(Lines, "BCDF")
# False
```

---

**Note 1**: `Lines` can be written as:

```
Lines=[('B', 'C'), ('D', 'A'), ('D', 'C'), ('A', 'B'), ('D', 'B')]
```

The parenthesis `()` and comma `,` have no additional effect here, you can drop them :-) .

**Note 2**: The `geometry` parameter for `check_geometry` can be any iterable (tuples, lists, strings):

```
check_geometry(lines, "BCD") == check_geometry(lines, ('B', 'C', 'D'))
```

Creating and passing a `tuple` to it seems somewhat odd in this case (alas, you might have a good reason to do so). Unless reasons require it, I would suggest going with strings as the value for parameter `geometry`.

Comment: Thank you... I use your answer, and it works for triangle, but for other geometry.. it's still not work
`def check_geometry(Lines,geometry):
    dataE = [x for x in (itertools.combinations(geometry, 2))]
    sLines = [tuple(sorted(l)) for l in Lines]
    return all(l1 in sLines for l1 in dataE)`

Comment: @ErnaPiantari I'll edit my code in a bit to add something that I believe will generalize to geometries with more edges. Give me a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 3):

> I think A,B,C can be string or whatever which define a point that set up a line

Okay, I'll be using strings for my answer then, you should be able to adjust the code to your needs.

```
def check_for_triangle(tri, lines):
    lines_needed = zip(tri, (tri[1], tri[2], tri[0]))
    return all(line in lines or line[::-1] in lines for line in lines_needed)

lines=[('B', 'C'), ('D', 'A'), ('D', 'C'), ('A', 'B'), ('D', 'B')]
tri1 = ('B', 'C', 'D')
tri2 = ('A', 'B', 'E')

print(check_for_triangle(tri1, lines)) # True
print(check_for_triangle(tri2, lines)) # False
```

The idea is to generate all lines (represented by a pair of points) we need to find in `lines` for a given triangle with `zip`. After that, we check whether all these lines can be found in `lines`.
Checking for `line[::-1]` as well is needed because the line `('A', 'B')` is the same line as `('B', 'A')`.